# How does CreateObject determine which version to open when more than one?

Tags: vba

On a remote server we have 3 versions of SEER-SEM installed (v8.2, v8.3, v8.4). When I execute CreateObject("SEER_SEM.Documents"), what determines which version of the SEER-SEM application that opens?  I have no control over multiple versions being installed.

Comment: There is usually a `CurrentVersion` value in the registry... usually

Comment: for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fee8d3d-3a65-4d03-b4c1-a9b55ece1ffc/createobject-and-dll-selection-without-clsid?forum=isvvba#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20CreateObject%20to%20create%C2%A0a%20%22ADODB.Recordset%22